# Google Script CardService.newButtonSet() is getting null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my script attached to a Google Spreadsheet I have a custom menu item to start / stop scripts. Conditionaly to actual state stored elsewhere I wanted to change prompt window. A problem is that it seems `CardService.newButtonSet()` is getting null, so addition of buttons causes errors.

```
  var state = true //Comes from DocumentProperties
  var onButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Spustit")
  var offButton = CardService.newTextButton().setText("Pozastavit")
  var cancelButton = ui.Button.CANCEL
  var buttonSet

  if (state == "true"){
    msg = "Do you want to stop the scripts?"
    title = "Automatic update is on"
    // Here I get the error: "Cannot find method addButton(Button)"
    buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(offButton).addButton(cancelButton)
  } else if (state == "false"){
    msg = "Do you want allow the scripts"
    title = "Automatic update is off"
    buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(onButton).addButton(cancelButton)
  } else {
    msg = "Do you want to switch automation on or off?"
    title = "Automation"
    buttonSet = CardService.newButtonSet().addButton(onButton).addButton(offButton).addButton(cancelButton)
  }
```

Do you have a tip, what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/

> Currently you can only use this service to construct Gmail add-ons.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't expected the reason is so simple.